# Cisco 1142: Gather "show int dot11Radio N statistics" Data via SNMP?

Tags: cisco, wireless, snmp, monitoring, cisco-wireless

I have a Cisco 1142 access point and would like to collect the statistics shown by the command "show int dot11Radio [N] statistics" command via SNMP. Specifically, I want to collect the number of bytes transmitted and received by the specified radio at each data rate for graphing and radio link performance analysis purposes.

I've looked around with snmpwalk but have not been able to find the OIDs that correspond to these counters. If anyone knows them or can suggest a more effective way to try to find them, I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: Is this an autonomous access point?

Comment: Yes, that's a good point. This is an autonomous AP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was not able to gather this data through SNMP. Instead, I had to write an 'expect' script which connects to the AP via SSH, runs the command mentioned in the question, then scrapes the returned data.

Answer (score 4):

According to [this list](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/wireless/access_point/12-3_7_JA/configuration/guide/i1237sc/s37mib.html), none of those MIBs carry per-rate statistics. Looking through all the v1 and v2 MIBs, I see nothing to indicate a way to get the per-rate stats.

[Cisco IOS MIB Locator](http://tools.cisco.com/ITDIT/MIBS/MainServlet?ReleaseSel=3764&PlatformSel=18&fsSel=1396) for my specific 1242. Use "New Search" to get the specifics for your 1142.